# What is the difference between Authorization and Authentication in Google Analytics API?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am still getting confused in understanding the concepts of authorization and authentication in Google Analytics API.

I created the new project at [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)  and enabled the Google Analytics API. But why they are asking these two things in API & Auth section?

Can Anyone give me any real life example which gives clear cut idea about these two things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Authentication** is the process of identifying yourself. When you log in to a service, you authenticate yourself by using some credentials. This credentials usually are a pair of username and password. If the provided credentials are correct then we can say that you have successfully authenticated yourself. But it doesn't means you can do anything on the system. For example maybe your account has been banned or you don't have permission to access the resource.

**Authorization** is the process of checking if you have the right to do something. To do this, first you have to authenticate yourself, because without knowing who you are it is not possible for someone to check if you have the right to do something or not.

Just imagine an invite-only party. When you arrive, at the door a big guy asks your name. You will say that you're Akilsree1, so you have authenticated yourself. Then the guy will check if your name is on the list of invited people or not, so he will authorize you to enter the party or maybe he will say that you cannot enter because you're not on the list (you do not have permission).

**Edit:**

In case of the Google Analytics API things are a little bit trickier.
Basically this is what happening:

1. When you use their API in your app, the user will be redirected to Google to log in (user authentication).
2. Then when your app tries to do something in behalf of the user, he/she will be asked by Google to give permission to your app to do so (authorization).
3. After that your app will receive a token which can be used by the app to authenticate itself when uses the API to do that specific thing (app authentication)

More details you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization).

Comment: Thank You so much @sc3w for giving Real life example. Can you tell me the varitation between them in Google Analytics API?

Answer (score 2):

Authentication meaning recognizing the subject identity. Like, does it exist in the DB?

Authorization meaning granting access to a resource. Like, can this user/role access X page.

Comment: Simple and Short. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In simple language if you want to understand

- Authorization is level of access rights that a user has i.e. the
  amount of information which he is authorized to access. Example: The
  data that a normal user can see in a system will be quite different
  from the data that admin user will be able to view and manipulate.
  This difference is achieved by means of authorization.
- Authentication simply means the submission of valid tokens(i.e.
  username,password in most cases) which are recognized by the system
  and by which system will grant access of system to particular user

Google analytics API requires authorization token for every request sent to it. and OAuth2.0 is the protocol used

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Great Help @Vihar , Can you tell me one thing , which among  Authorization or Authentication data vary  for one user to another in Google Analytics API?